# Is this when I should be creating a class?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get to grip with Swift and wanted some advice...

I have a UIView that exists on a number of screens; specifically, it's a logo that uses a number of elements/parameters to style it correctly i.e. shadow, shape, image etc.

For my first viewcontroller I set this up as a function that is called from the viewDidLoad function. Then in my second viewcontroller I have the same logo... here is my question,

Should I load the first view controller from the story board and then reference the function in the second viewcontroller OR should I have just made the logo a class that either viewcontroller can reference? My gut says it should be a class...

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can also move the function to the singleton class and make that function return the UIView. now whenever you need that view just call the function and get the view, now do whatever you want to do with the view.

Comment: The key phrase is *"I have a `UIView` that exists on a number...."* While there are a number of design patterns, in almost any of them - particularly MVC - you want to *separate* this view from it's controller. Now the only question to ask is how you *create* the view - through IB or in code? If it's IB, consider a NIB file. If it's code, do it's compliment - subclass `UIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **WARNING!** As I pointed out on another answer, **DO NOT** load the same nib from within `awakeFromNib`, or else you'll create an infinite loop of loading nibs.

Your gut instinct is correct, I would say. Create a custom class for your reusable view to go in. If you decide to create a nib for your class, I recommend instantiating it from a static function.

```
class ReusableView: UIView {
    static func newFromNib() -> ReusableView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: ReusableView.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ReusableView", bundle: bundle)
        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? ReusableView else {
            preconditionFailure("Could not instantiate ReusableView")
        }
        return view
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Configuration ONLY if you use a Nib.
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Configuration if you DO NOT use a nib
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in a view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var reusableViewContainer: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a new instance of your reusable view
        let reusableView = ReusableView.newFromNib()

        // If not using a nib, just use the 'init(frame:)' method
//        let reusableView = ReusableView(frame: .zero)

        // Add your reusable view to the view hierarchy
        self.reusableViewContainer.addSubview(reusableView)

        // Layout your view as necessary:
        // For example, if using AutoLayout:
        self.reusableViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reusableView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.reusableViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reusableView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.reusableViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reusableView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.reusableViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reusableView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Of course, you don't have to use a container view. Place it wherever you need it in your view hierarchy, and lay it out as you do for other views.

Answer (score 1):

For a reusable view you’d create a XIB in which you design the view plus a view controller class in which you instantiate the xib, like this:

```
class ReusableView: UIView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ReusableView", bundle: bundle)

        if let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView {
            view.frame = bounds
            addSubview(view)
        }
    }
}
```

In your view controller(s), you’d then simply place a placeholder UIView at the desired location and set its custom type to `ReusableView`. By connecting an outlet from this view into your view controller you’d have access to the view’s properties.

Please note that you will have to leave the Custom View property in the XIB set as UIView and set File’s Owner to `ReusableView` instead. Otherwise you’ll create an infinite loop.

Comment: If the view instantiated from the nib is also a `ReusableView`, won’t this just kick off an infinite loop?

Comment: @Harry Robinson: Nope. The instantiated view is an _instance_ of `ReusableView`—you can have as many instances of a class as you’d like.

Comment: But `awakeFromNib` is called after a view has been loaded from a nib. And when the first view is loaded from a nib, you then load another one from a nib. I don't see how this doesn't create a recursion.

Comment: I just created a sample project to test this, and it does indeed create an infinite loop.

Comment: Well, it _does_ work if you make sure that within the xib you don’t set the view to `ReusableView` but leave it as `UIView` instead. For proper connection, you set File’s Owner to `ReusableView`. This scheme has been working in numerous projects of mine.

Comment: If that's the case, then 1) That's a major pitfall you should note in your answer. 2) That's very confusing since the view inside "ReusableView.xib" isn't a `ReusableView`, which goes against common convention. 3) Sorry for not understanding, but you did just say a few comments ago that the instantiated view from the nib was also, in fact, an instance of `ReusableView`.

Comment: @ABeard89: Correct, it is confusing... I’ve updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out.